How to enable wifi driver
I installed Ubuntu on my laptop for the first time, and when I tried to connect to a WiFi network none would appear. I've been trying to fix it for some time now, reading forums and with YouTube, but I haven't had any luck yet. I think my driver is disabled, and I don't know how to enable it.


What does rfkill list show?

In settings - is aeroplane mode enabled? And if you click on the Wi-Fi tab at the top of settings, is the toggle switch at the top orange (ie enabled)?

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?
